# Zip Utility with encryption option

Tags: software-recommendation, zip, encryption

Is there any good zip application for Mac OS X similar to [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) (Windows only) which is free, compatible with many formats, and offers encryption options?

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Keka - the free Max OS X file archiver](http://www.kekaosx.com/)
[image]

> With 7z and Zip you will have the
>   opportunity to create password
>   encrypted files to better protect your
>   privacy. It's as easy as write your
>   password in the box, and drag and drop
>   files to Keka in the dock.

---

Another way is to run the command in your Terminal.app:

```
$ zip -e myzip.zip <files>
```

After the command you will be prompted for a password. Instead of the single files you can specify a folder, too.

---

I don't know of any more apps that allow you to create archives with many formats. For decrompression there are multiple great apps (The Unarchiver, Stuffit Expander).
You can give [**7zipX**](http://sixtyfive.xmghosting.com/products/7zx/) a try, too.

Some paid alternatives:

- [BetterZip](http://macitbetter.com/)
- [StuffIt](http://www.stuffit.com/mac-stuffit.html)
- [Archiver](http://archiverapp.com/)

Comment: What encryption does `zip -e` use? AES? The `man` page only says that it encrypts with the password entered.

Comment: Couldn't find anything. But man page also states `And where security  is truly  important,  use strong encryption such as Pretty Good Privacy instead of the relatively weak standard encryption provided by zipfile utilities.` So I guess you should care about encryption yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The unarchiver and simplyRAR in addition to keka.